# Cant add a text control without blocking the toolbar in wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython, sizer

I reproduced the error here;

```
import wx
import debug

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):


    def __init__(self, parent):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "Test")
        self.SetSize((600,500))

        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        toolbar = wx.ToolBar(self, -1, style=wx.TB_HORIZONTAL | wx.NO_BORDER)
        toolbar.Realize()
        vbox.Add(toolbar, 0, border=5)

app = wx.App(0)

frame = MyFrame(None)
app.SetTopWindow(frame)
frame.Show()

app.MainLoop()
```

Now wherever i add this line to add a text control;

```
self.control = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
```

it appears over the toolbar. I read the documentation and followed some tutorials but still i cant fully grasp the concept. How can i achieve what i want? I want the text control to appear below the toolbar and fit the remaining space.

Comment: I believe you're missing the crucial line of code here that causes the problem. Please post the example that demonstrates the problem, instead of (or in addition to) posting different code and then trying to describe the changes that led to the problem.

Comment: But I have a guess: You're not adding the `TextCtrl` to the `BoxSizer`, you're adding it directly to the `Frame`. The whole point of the `BoxSizer` is to automatically lay out its sub-widgets, so you can just add another control and it will appear below the previous one, which sounds like exactly what you want.

Comment: @abarnert This excact code show the problem, text control places itself over the toolbar. Are you getting a different output? Actual code is kinda long and most of the variables and function names are in turkish. If you want i can put a pastebin link. And for the second comment i tried that and nothing happened but i'll do it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are a couple of issues

1. you haven't added the `TextCtrl` to the `BoxSizer`, so it won't get laid out
2. you haven't set the sizer for the `Frame`

You can do something like this...

```
def __init__(self, parent):

    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "Test")
    self.SetSize((600,500))

    toolbar = wx.ToolBar(self, -1, style=wx.TB_HORIZONTAL | wx.NO_BORDER)
    toolbar.Realize()

    self.control = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)

    vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    vbox.Add(toolbar, 0, border=5)
    vbox.Add(self.control, 1, border=5)

    self.SetSizer(vbox)
```

...but it's probably better to use the `Frame`'s [`CreateToolBar()`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxframe.html#wxframecreatetoolbar) method, then you don't have to worry about its layout...

```
def __init__(self, parent):

    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "Test")
    self.SetSize((600,500))

    toolbar = self.CreateToolBar(style=wx.TB_HORIZONTAL | wx.NO_BORDER)
    toolbar.Realize()

    self.control = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)

    vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    vbox.Add(self.control, 1, border=5)

    self.SetSizer(vbox)
```

...indeed, if the `TextCtrl` is the only other thing in the frame, you don't even need the sizer...

```
def __init__(self, parent):

    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "Test")
    self.SetSize((600,500))

    toolbar = self.CreateToolBar(style=wx.TB_HORIZONTAL | wx.NO_BORDER)
    toolbar.Realize()

    self.control = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
```

Comment: I used the first example of yours with a sizer, and now it doesnt show up over the toolbar but its aligned to left and very narrow. How can i make it so the control fills the entire area?

Comment: @ÇağdaşSalur: There's no way anyone can answer your question without writing a medium-sized tutorial, which isn't appropriate for SO. Work through [a simple tutorial](http://wiki.wxpython.org/How%20to%20Learn%20wxPython#Read_the_wxPython_tutorials), and then read the [`Sizer`](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Sizer-class.html) docs for any details that weren't covered. Once you get the basics of widget layout in wx, what you're trying to do is obvious; until you do, it's next to impossible.

Comment: @ÇağdaşSalur If you're adding the text control *after* constructing and showing the frame, you may need to ask the sizer to do its layout again by calling `self.GetSizer().Layout()` on the frame.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the actual problem code, it's hard to be sure, but I'm betting that you want this:

```
vbox.Add(self.control)
```

Or, if the `TextCtrl` isn't being built inside `__init__`, make that `self.vbox.Add`, and of course change the `vbox` references in `__init__` to `self.vbox`.

Quoting from [the docs](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.BoxSizer-class.html):

> The basic idea behind a box sizer is that windows will most often be laid out in rather simple basic geometry, typically in a row or a column or nested hierarchies of either. A wx.BoxSizer will lay out its items in a simple row or column, depending on the orientation parameter passed to the constructor.

This is exactly you want—you want to put a `TextCtrl` to get laid out vertically beneath a `Toolbar`. If you put them both into the same `BoxSizer`, this will happen automatically.

But if you put the `TextCtrl` directly into a `Frame`, and also put the `BoxSizer` with the `Toolbar` inside it into the same `Frame`, you haven't told wx how to lay out the controls within the `Frame`.

Comment: i added `vbox.Add(control)` after the `vbox.Add(toolbar, 0, border=5)` and nothing changes. What am i missing?

Comment: @ÇağdaşSalur See my answer below.